# Android: Relate 2 spinner/ variable to string-array

Tags: android, arrays, string, spinner, android-spinner

I want to do a 2 spinner activity that the second spinner depends on the first one, similar than the state/city example. I populate the spinners with the string arrays, so heres my

> strings.xml

```
 <string-array name="Jornadas">
        <item >1</item>
        <item >2</item>
        <item >3</item>
        <item >4</item>
        <item >5</item>

</string-array>

<string-array name="partidosj1">
            <item >c11</item>
            <item >c12</item>
            <item >c15</item>
            <item >c13</item>
    </string-array>
<string-array name="partidosj2">
            <item >c1</item>
            <item >c2</item>
            <item >c5</item>
            <item >c3</item>
    </string-array>

//and so on....
```

Heres my oncreate

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


Spinner jornadas = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Spinner partidos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Jornadas, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
jornadas.setAdapter(adapter1);

jornadas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
    String a= "partidosj "+pos;

    }

   });
 ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.a, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 

 //Do whatever
}}
```

So the string "a" has the same name that the string array that I want to populate the second spinner but I cannot refer It on the array adapter because it has to be a int variable. Is there any way to convert the "a" variable into a correct string-array resource?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier(a, "array", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Where do I have to insert this line into my code? I had inserted just after the a variable, and when I define the second spinner adapter I have to put arrayId like this?   ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,arrayId, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

Comment: yes, the values of `R.array.partidosj1` is stored in `arrayId`. Use it as normally.